# Relation between covariance and uncorrelation/independence

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, covariance

I need to have an explanation... If I have a covariance equal to zero, the random variables are only uncorrelated, or are uncorrelated and independent at the same time?

Thanks

Comment: If the covariance is $0$ we call them uncorrelated. They need not be independent.

Comment: Wonder what's wrong with a google search: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncorrelatedness_(probability_theory). Not to mention other posts on this site discussing this.

Comment: @StubbornAtom your link is very helpfull but I can't see the problem to ask in a forum to have an explanation from "real" people.

Comment: That 'zero correlation does not imply independence' is a popular query and comprehensive answers to this question have been provided on this very site. If you performed a minimal search you wouldn't ask this question.

Comment: @StubbornAtom are you here only to make a fuss?? Other users replied in a kind way to me, you are just being polemical. End of discussion thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are uncorrelated but not independent, in general.
Conversely, if the variables are Independent they are also uncorrelated.

EDIT 2:
If the model is Gaussian, and to be more precise, if $(X,Y)$ are jointly Gaussian, Uncorrelation and independence are the same

Proof:

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_{X}\sigma_{Y}\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}[\frac{(x-\mu_{X})^2}{\sigma_{X}^2}-2\rho\frac{(x-\mu_{X})(y-\mu_{Y})}{\sigma_{X}\sigma_{X}}+\frac{(y-\mu_{Y})^2}{\sigma_{Y}^2}]}$$

Letting $\rho=0$ that means incorrelation between $X$ and $Y$ immediately we get

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$$

that means also independence.

Comment: Are you sure it is an "only if"?

Comment: @user10354138 :no, I am not sure...amended

Comment: When you say "If the model is Gaussian" you presumably mean multivariate Gaussian.  It is possible to have two univariate Gaussian random variables which are uncorrelated but not independent

Comment: Good point @Henry. An article that explains this more: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent. Multivariate Gaussian is also known as jointly Gaussian in some texts.

Comment: @Henry : at first I supposed that my answer was enough as an explanation for the O.P. Now I edited again my answer to be more precise.

Comment: @tommik the first part of the jointly gaussian PDF is: $f_{xy}(x,y)=\frac{1}{2 \pi \sigma _{x}\sigma _{y}\sqrt{1-\rho ^{2}}} ...$ right?

Comment: @BigBro : of course....today is a wrong day... :(

Comment: @tommik don't worry... Thanks to everyone for the help